Using sails.log.crit() in Sails.js with and without Winston
I'm working on a Node.js application using the Sails framework. I've noticed that the sails.log.crit() function works without integrating Winston, but I can't find any documentation or records on this function in the Sails.js documentation.
Can I reliably use sails.log.crit() in my application without Winston?
Are there any potential issues or limitations I should be aware of if I use sails.log.crit() without Winston integration?
Thanks in advance for your help!
What I Tried and Expected:
I tried using sails.log.crit() in my application and observed that it logs messages as expected. However, I couldn't find any official documentation about this function in the Sails.js docs. I expected to find detailed documentation on all logging functions provided by Sails, including sails.log.crit().
What Actually Happened:
Despite the function working correctly, the lack of documentation makes me uncertain about its reliability and future compatibility. I'm concerned about potential issues or limitations that might arise from using this undocumented feature.

There is nothing to worry about, you can depend on the documentation of sails.log.error as sails.log.crit() is an alias of sails.log.error() when no custom logger like Winston is provided, as the case is in sails.js by default
Technical Details
Under the hood, sails.log is an instance of 'captains-log'.
Source file: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/eb5fe320d5dac896734660bd51b2be2dbfc2bea7/lib/app/Sails.js#L5-L35

var CaptainsLog = require('captains-log');
function Sails() {

//....redacted

  // Ensure CaptainsLog exists
  this.log = CaptainsLog();
//....redacted
}


Below is a redacted code snippet from captains-log that decides when sails.log.error() should be used as a fallback for sails.log.crit()
Source file: https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log/blob/28fb8e0ce903e23d2eabf881bc4020223847ac54/index.js#L61-L76
// Fill in the gaps for the required log methods with
// reasonable guesses if the custom logger is missing any
// (only required method is `logger.log` or `logger.debug`)
// If no reasonable alternative is possible, don't log
    
//....redacted code

 *logger.crit = logger.crit ? logger.crit.bind(logger) : (logger.error ? logger.error.bind(logger) : _.noop);  
//...redacted code

According to the readme file of captains-log

Formerly, this module encapsulated Winston, a popular logger by
@indexzero and the gals/guys over at Nodejitsu. But eventually, we
made Winston optional to make captains-log as lightweight as possible
and reduce the number of npm installs and require()s necessary for its
usage in other modules.

If you are interested in using Winston, the readme gave the following instruction

To boot up a captains-log that writes to Winston, do the following:
var log = require('captains-log')({
  custom: new (require('winston').Logger)({
    levels     : ...,
    transports : ...
  })
});


Visit https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log/blob/master/README.md#using-winston for the complete instructions.
To use Winston as a custom logger in sails.js you can follow this instruction from Sails.js Documentation, you can adapt the instruction to use any custom logger package as well.
